# Working T-SQL query gives error when values assigned to variables

Tags: sql-server, syntax, variable-assignment

The following query works.  However, when I uncomment the commented lines in order to assign query variables to my locally-defined variables, I get a syntax error at the final ";".

```
 DECLARE @tmp_total_ct int = 0;
 DECLARE @tmp_closed_ct int = 0;

 --SELECT @tmp_total_ct = tot_ct, @tmp_closed_ct = cls_ct
 --    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_ct,
        SUM(IIF(is_closed = 1, 1, 0)) AS cls_ct
              FROM  corp.CashDealDetails
                INNER JOIN WidgeStores wstrs
                   ON corp.CashDealDetails.abbrev = wstrs.abbrev
              WHERE mall_id IN
                (SELECT mall_ndx FROM WidgeStores wstrs
                   WHERE wstrs.abbrev IN 
                      (SELECT abbrev FROM @tmpMkts)
                   AND wstrs.[is_opn] = 1
                )
                AND YEAR(closing_dt) = 2012
        --);
```

I believe that I'm using the correct syntax for assigning query values to user-defined variables, as explained in other posts on these threads.  Where exactly is the syntax error?

Comment: Alias the main sub query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 declare @tmp_total_ct int
 declare @tmp_closed_ct int

 SELECT @tmp_total_ct = tot_ct, @tmp_closed_ct = cls_ct
     FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_ct,
        SUM(IIF(is_closed = 1, 1, 0)) AS cls_ct
              FROM  corp.CashDealDetails
                INNER JOIN WidgeStores wstrs
                   ON corp.CashDealDetails.abbrev = wstrs.abbrev
              WHERE mall_id IN
                (SELECT mall_ndx FROM WidgeStores wstrs
                   WHERE wstrs.abbrev IN 
                      (SELECT abbrev FROM @tmpMkts)
                   AND wstrs.[is_opn] = 1
                )
                AND YEAR(closing_dt) = 2012
) a 

print @tmp_total_ct
print @tmp_closed_ct
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  For the sake of clarity, I added the subquery alias as a prefix to the variables in the assignment.  So, "a.tot_ct" and "a.cls_ct".   SQL Server doesn't require this, however.

Comment: Right, I always try to use aliases whenever it will make it clearer even if not required!